# I can't download PyCharm for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, python, python-3

I have had my raspberry Pi 3b for a few months so I'm just getting used to it. I would however want to install PyCharm because I want to use my Pi to program on rather than my PC. Any ideas would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing mixed messages about running PyCharm directly on the Raspberry Pi, but there's an existing thread on StackOverflow that seems to mention you can run it there (see below).

One thing is certain: Jetbrains does provide a way of doing remote development between a PyCharm installation on a Laptop/Desktop and a remote Pi, but that's not what you seem to be asking.

Here's that link, please report back if you are successful or not:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732918/install-rpi-module-on-pycharm

Good Luck!

Comment: The only problem is, the profesional edition cost money and I'd like to do it for free! I've got no money to spare! Otherwise, this would probably work. Does it work with the community edition?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason pycharm failed for me on my rpi3 was due to insufficient memory for the JRE. Increased physical memory.

From Error Log:
9 There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue
4 Native nemory allocation (malloc) failed to atlocate 381448 bytes for Chunk:.new

## Possible reasons:

The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit

## Possible solutions:

Reduce memory load on the system
Increase physical memory or swap space
Check if swap backing store is full
Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
I
Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
Decrease number of Java threads
Set target Vodk"Cache fath Suf Refe/vedcodecachesizes
This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
Out of Memory Error (arena.cpp:197), pid=6883, tid=6912